# Data from review steamapi is not being displayed. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, steam

I am making an api call to the steam review api with this link: "[api link](https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/1389990?json=1&language=english)"

I have used another link with my code and was able to get responses and even display the data on my screen, so I have no faulty code. I am currently using this to try and get the result content: `comment.reviews.review`

This is my complete code:

```
function Home() {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchComments();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(comments);
  }, [comments]);
  const fetchComments = async () => {
    const response = await axios(
      "https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/1389990?json=1&language=english"
    );
    setComments(response.data);
  };
  var limitComments = comments.slice(0, 3);

  return (
    {limitComments &&
       limitComments.map((comment) => (
          <p>{comment.reviews.review}</p>
                        
     ))}
   );
}

export default Home;
```

What is wrong with request? I have tried using different keys like `comment.author.reviews.review`.

Comment: Is your API working correctly? I got `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` while trying. I am just guessing you might be getting that error and your `setComments(response.data);` is not getting updated.

Comment: @mchowdam this the official steam api so it works correctly.